# we can say about the convergence of $\Lambda_k=\varphi_1\circ\cdots\circ \varphi_{k-1} \circ \varphi_{k}$??

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

Given a sequence differentiable $\varphi_k:\mathbb{R}^m\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $\vert \varphi_k^{\prime}\vert \leq \alpha$ with $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

that can say about the convergence of $\Lambda_k=\varphi_1\circ\cdots\circ \varphi_{k-1} \circ \varphi_{k}$??

I believe that converges uniformly to a constant, by the chain rule get: $$\vert \Lambda_{k+m}(x)-\Lambda_{k}(x)\vert \leq \alpha^{k}\vert \varphi_{k+1}\circ\cdots\circ \varphi_{k+m}(x)-x \vert$$
But $\vert \varphi_{k+1}\circ\cdots\circ \varphi_{k+m}(x)-x \vert$ is bounded for $m,k$ sufficiently large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For a counterexample, take $\phi_n(x)=\frac12x+a_n$. No matter what $a_k$ is for $k<n$, you can always fix $a_n$ so that $\phi_1\circ\cdots\circ\phi_n(0)=b_n$ for whatever value of $b_n$ you choose. Pick $a_1$, $a_2$, … in order. The point here being, $\phi_1\circ\cdots\circ\phi_{n-1}$ has the form $\frac1{2^{n-1}}x+\text{constant}$, so just pick $a_n$ so that $\phi_1\circ\cdots\circ\phi_{n-1}(a_n)=b_n$.